# Twig Navigation macro

Tags: php, yii2, twig

I'm trying to create a nested navigation menu using a PHP array and outputting it using Twig. I'm using Yii2 as the PHP framework.
My goal to achieve two things:

- Add a `.active` automatically to the nested/children items (they should be able to be deeper than 2 levels).
- Automatically get the parent slug on the `item.url`, so you don't need to type it out on every child in the array.

Here's the PHP array:

```
return [
    [
        'label' => 'Home',
        'url' => '/',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'About',
        'url' => 'about',
        'children' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Secondary 1',
                'url' => 'secondary-1',
            ],
            [
                'label' => 'Secondary 2',
                'url' => 'secondary-2',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Foo',
        'url' => 'foo',
        'children' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Bar',
                'url' => 'bar',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

And here's the Twig template code so far:

```
{% macro nav(navigation) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}

    {% for item in navigation %}
        {% set active = app.request.getPathInfo starts with item.url or item.url == '/' and app.request.getPathInfo is empty %}

        <li>
            <a href="{{ baseUrl }}/{{ item.url|trim('/',side='left') }}" {{ active ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>{{ item.label }}</a>
            {% if item.children is iterable %}
                <ul>
                    {{ macros.nav(item.children) }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as macros %}

<nav id="navigation" class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

        <ul>
            {{ macros.nav(navigation) }}
        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This sounds more like a Specification than a questions!

Comment: To ask On Topic question, please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. My question is clear, what I'm trying to achieve is clear, I've offered sample working code.

Comment: Does that code do what you want it to?

Comment: Yes, besides the two points I mentioned in the question!

Comment: I still maintain thats a specification. The idea of SO is that you code it to do what you want, **all of what you want**. And only then when it fails in some way does it become a question on how to fix it rather than a request for someone else to code it for you.

Comment: OK. Well, these kinds of answers chase people away from asking questions on SO (I'm not alone here). I feel you're being unnecessarily stubborn and pedantic. If I wasn't stuck, I would've solved it myself already. You could also give me useful feedback: for instance, if you think I'm formulating my question badly, suggest I edit it and ask in a different way.

Comment: I didnt answer I commented. And that does not stop others from giving you answers if they have the time to understand your requirement and post a answer.  Maybe someone will if you wait long enough. However if they dont, you may now understand why

Comment: cool it down guys, @RiggsFolly is also right about what he is saying. and i agree that sometimes we get stuck, and dont know what to do. You might add some progress over the time and update the question till someone could add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the full URL it is required that you pass your current URL down into the recursion.

```
{% macro nav(navigation, parent) %}
    {% import _self as macros %}

    {% for item in navigation %}
        {% set active = app.request.getPathInfo starts with item.url or item.url == '/' and app.request.getPathInfo is empty %}

        <li>
            <a href="http://www.example.com/{{ parent |default('') }}{{ item.url|trim('/') }}" {{ active ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>{{ item.label }}</a>
            {% if not item.children|default([]) is empty %}
                <ul>
                    {{ macros.nav(item.children|default([]), (parent?:'')~item.url~'/') }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>

    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: As for determining whether the link is active, I wouldn't bother with testing whether the item slug is inside the current URL. You would need a better strategy for this, but I have to few information to give a proper answer on this.

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. For the active item, I tried this now and it works. Not sure if it's too messy though:
`{% set active = pp.request.pathinfo ~ '/' matches "|#{ item.url }/|" or item.url == '/' and app.request.getPathInfo is empty %}`

Comment: I just tested your above 'parent' code. And it works! Brilliant, really appreciate your clean solution!